# How to find the foot of a perpendicular given one point and a line with two points

Tags: python, numpy

All points are 3-d vector, suppose one point is a, the line with two points (b and c), now draw a perpendicular line from a to the line bc, the foot is, e.g. d, how to find the coordinate of point d with numpy? Thanks

supposing:

```
a {x1, y1, z1}
b {x2, y2, z2}
c {x3, y3, z3}
```

I guess cross product will help, however, still have no idea, coule someone shed a light on this, Thanks!

```
# 3 points
def getfoot(a, b, c):
    foot = np.cross(a-b, b-c).... # no idea
    return root
```

the d is either inside or outside of bc.

Comment: Can't you just use the formula to calculate the line equation from two points and then use the formula to calculate the "foot"? I think this is a maths question.

Comment: That looks a lot like homework.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question, it is a mathematics question

Comment: The math has been done, all you need is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection .Other than that you should only need to know `numpy.vdot(a, b)` , which is vector dot product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the answer from [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72528/how-can-i-project-a-3d-point-onto-a-3d-line)

just project a to the line ab, not sure this is the simplest one.

Post my code here.

```
def get_foot(p, a, b):
    ap = p - a
    ab = b - a
    result = a + np.dot(ap, ab)/np.dot(ab, ab) * ab
    return result
```

Comment: Answers will be downvoted if they do not add value beyond a link.